# Format DateTime-object for calendar event, retrieved from google calendar api

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

Trying to format the DateTime object retrieved from the google calendar API. It's now printing the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", and want it to print on the format "dayOfWeek, dd monthName".

Example: **Wednesday, 28 August.**

Here is my code to get the start time of the event:

```java
DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
```

Comment: you can format date with  date `formatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`joda`](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time), you can achieve this by doing :

```
DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM");
String requiredFormat = fmt.print(start);
```

Comment: Had to get the DateTime from "com.google.api.client.util.DateTime" to "org.joda.time.DateTime" before using the **fmt.print()**, bacause  it couldn't resolve method **print(com.google.api.client.util.DateTime)**. 
But it works perfectly now, thanks.